# Does java support inline declaration and assignment in a conditional statement?

Tags: java

First way (successful):

```
               double minMed = 0.0;
               // Other logic ..
               minMed = (newMed= median) < minMed ? newMed : minMed;
```

Second way (compiler error - "Expression expected"):

```
               double minMed = 0.0;
               // Other logic ..
               minMed = (double newMed=median) < minMed ? newMed : minMed;
```

[image]

The analog to this in *python* is the walrus operator `:=` .

So is the inline declaration of a variable in a statement *only* valid in a *for* loop like this?

```
for (int i=0;i<MAX; i++)
```

Comment: Your second way does not make any sense; following Java's scopes, the newMed would be discarded instantly after the call is over, so allowing a declaration would be is just useless and cumbersome. Secondly, the declaration inside the for loop is not an inline declaration; same goes for try/resource control statement. The structure gets dismantled into several "lines" of bytecode, but still be wrapped up inside its own scope.

Comment: C# for example has the weakness that it basically does the same, it just doesn't wrap it all in its own scope. So having a for variable with same name as another var outside the loop, even if it's declared later (after the loop), you cannot use that name twice, because in C# bytecode it would already be declared by the "unrolled"/destructured loop.

Comment: As you have alrady tried it and got a compilation error, why are you even asking?

Comment: @user207421  You can infer I am interested in a similar approach. Should I make that explicit in the question?

Comment: Closing of this question did not necessarily  follow the typical guidelines. It is not a typo or similar.   But in any case the question was updated with code and comment clarifications to improve it. The specific feature mentioned is similar to other java language features and there is a direct equivalent in some other languages e.g. python. There is a reasonable (and accepted) answer that provides useful information.

Comment: I wanted this feature yet again today in a conditional return statement . This "walrus operator" is a nice but missing feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, the inline declaration of a variable in a statement is not *only* valid in a *for* loop.

It is also valid in *try*-with-resource statement, [JLS 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> ...
> A resource specification uses variables to denote resources for the try statement, either by **declaring local variables with initializer expressions** or ...

Example:

```
try (var rd = new BufferedReader(...)) {
    ...
}
```

---

After searching the [JLS 19 Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-19.html) page, I believe only the two `for` statements and the `try`-with-resource statement accept this kind of declaration (despite Lambda-expressions).

---

Confirmed by [JLS 14.4. Local Variable Declaration Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4):

> Apart from local variable declaration statements, a local variable can be declared by the header of a basic `for` statement ([§14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1)), an enhanced `for` statement ([§14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)), or a `try`-with-resources statement ([§14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)).

Comment: This appears to be the most complete and directly applicable answer.

Comment: but IMHO, even if allowed inside the conditional statement, it would be hard to read/understand (same true for `minMed = (newMed= median) < minMed ? newMed : minMed;`) - I would prefer two distinct assignments

Answer (score 4):

No, java does not support inline declaration and assignment in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

No, a declaration of the type in the assignment is invalid.

Plus, you cannot use the variable that you are declaring at the right side, as part of the initialization, because you will get a compiler error that the variable "might not be initialized".

In addition, you can have compound variable declaration, each other separated by comma, but they all must be of the same type.

For example, a valid variable declaration and initialization is this one:

```
double  newMed =0, 
        median = 1,
        minMed = (newMed = median) < median ? newMed : 0;
```

Notice that to define "minMed", i am using variable which have been already inizialized, otherwise, you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, far more sensible to `stream()` the list and map to a `double` based on the `median` and find the minimum. Something like,

```
double minMed = lis.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x.median).min().orElse(0);
```